# If $A$ is a maximal normal abelian subgroup of a nilpotent group $G$, then $A = C_G(A)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need help understanding the following proof:

> Since $A$ is abelian, it follows $A \le C=C_G(A)$. Suppose $A \not=C$: then $C/A$ is a non-trivial normal subgroup of the nilpotent group $G/A$, and so it follows there is some $xA \in (C/A) \cap Z(G/A)$ with $x \notin A$. Now $\langle x,A \rangle$ is abelian and normal in $G$ because $\langle x, A \rangle/A \le Z(G/A).$ Hence $x \in A$ by maximality of $A$.

I don't understand the reasoning for the normality of $\langle x, A \rangle $ in $G$ near the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if (1) $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, (2) $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $H$, and (3) $K/H$ is a normal subgroup of $G/H$, then it follows that $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.  This is easy to check.

We have $\langle x,A \rangle/A$ is normal in $G/A$, since every subgroup of the center is normal.  The above result implies that $\langle x,A \rangle$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: Nice +1 The result you mention in your first lines i part of the *correspondence theorem*, a name that, perhaps, may ring a bell for other people.

Comment: Can you please also explain why $\langle x, A \rangle /A \le Z(G/A)$. Maybe this is a simple result, but I don't know how to see that it is true. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Never mind, I see now that it is obvious. Since $A, xA \in Z(G/A)$ so  $\langle x, A \rangle /A \le Z(G/A)$.

Comment: @Ted Does maximal mean proper in this? Because if it does, shouldn't this statement fail for abelian groups? For example if $A$ is $<[2]_4>$ inside $\Bbb Z_4$?

Comment: @Amontillado Maximal does not mean proper in this context.  It means any subgroup which is maximal among all normal abelian subgroups of $G$.  If $G$ is abelian, then $A = G$.